# Dropzone form into a global form : impossible to get the file with Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, file-upload, laravel-5, dropzone.js

I'm trying on the homepage on my website, to have a form which contains a dropzone area with a preview to see the file with three other inputs. Goal is that at validation, everything is stocked into the database and I'm able to open the document on another page.

The problem is that, whatever I try, it seems like I'm not able to get the file on the server side once the file is loaded with Dropzone.JS.

Each time on the server side I'm able to have the data of my form, but never the file itself, which gives me an error on the server (controller) side.

Furthermore, another problem is that the progress bar is leaving empty, and not even filling once I'm submitted the form. Best would be that it loads the file (putting the progress bar at 100%), then once it's "loaded", I can submit it with the rest of my form.

I'm using part of the code provided with the Bootstrap implementation : [dropzone-bootstrap](http://www.dropzonejs.com/bootstrap.html).

Here is my HTML form :

```
<form method="post" action="/upload-free-document" id="send-files-form" files="true" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<h3 class="form-title text-left">@lang('landing.get_started')</h3>
{{ csrf_field() }}
<div class="form-header">
    <div class="form-group icon-addon addon-lg">
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control wow fadeInUp" placeholder="@lang('landing.your_email')" required>
        <label for="email" class="glyphicon glyphicon-user wow fadeInUp" rel="tooltip" title="@lang('landing.your_email')"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group icon-addon addon-lg">
        <input type="text" name="signatories-email" id="signatories-email" class="form-control wow fadeInUp" placeholder="@lang('landing.signatories_email')" required>
        <label for="email" class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope wow fadeInUp" rel="tooltip" title="@lang('landing.your_email')"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12 input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon message-icon wow fadeInUp"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil message-glyph-icon"></span></span>
            <textarea id="document-message" name="document-message" rows="10" cols="20" class="form-control input-message wow fadeInUp" maxlength="1500" placeholder="@lang('landing.your_message')" required></textarea>
        </div>
        <span class="caracters-left"><span id="chars">1500</span> @lang('landing.caracters_left')</span>
    </div>

    <div id="actions" class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button upload-buttons add-file-button">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                <span>@lang('landing.add_file')</span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="table table-striped files" id="previews">
      <div id="template" class="file-row">
        <div>
            <span class="preview"><img data-dz-thumbnail /></span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p class="name" data-dz-name></p>
            <strong class="error text-danger" data-dz-errormessage></strong>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p class="size" data-dz-size></p>
            <div class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0">
              <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%;" data-dz-uploadprogress></div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group last">
        <input type="submit" id="submit-document" class="btn btn-warning btn-block btn-lg" value="@lang('landing.demo_sign_document')">
    </div>
    <p class="privacy text-center">@lang('landing.privacy_text') <a href="privacy.html">@lang('landing.privacy_link')</a>.</p>
</div>
```

And here is the Dropzone configuration :

```
    // Get the template HTML and remove it from the doumenthe template HTML and remove it from the doument
var previewNode = document.querySelector("#template");
previewNode.id = "";
var previewTemplate = previewNode.parentNode.innerHTML;
previewNode.parentNode.removeChild(previewNode);

Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

var myDropzone = new Dropzone(document.body, { // Make the whole body a dropzone
    url: "/upload-free-document",
    thumbnailWidth: 80,
    thumbnailHeight: 80,
    parallelUploads: 20,
    previewTemplate: previewTemplate,
    autoQueue: false,
    previewsContainer: "#previews", // Define the container to display the previews
    clickable: ".fileinput-button", // Define the element that should be used as click trigger to select files.
    maxFiles: 1,
    acceptedFiles: ".pdf", //is this correct? I got an error if im using this
    maxFilesize: 3145728,
    parallelUploads: 1,
    uploadMultiple: false,
    autoProcessQueue: false,

    // The setting up of the dropzone
    init: function() {
        var myDropzone = this;

        $("#submit-document").click(function (e) {
            // e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            myDropzone.processQueue();
        }); 

        myDropzone.on("addedfile", function(file) {
            console.log("Fichier ajouté");
        });

        // Listen to the sendingmultiple event. In this case, it's the sendingmultiple event instead
        // of the sending event because uploadMultiple is set to true.
        this.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData) {
            console.log(formData);
            formData.append("email", $('#email').val());
            formData.append("_token", $('[name=_token').val());
            console.log("Fichier en cours d'envoi."); 
        });

        this.on("success", function(files, response) {
            // Gets triggered when the files have successfully been sent.
            // Redirect user or notify of success
             myDropzone.removeAllFiles();
            console.log("Succès de l'envoi.");
        });

        this.on("error", function(files, response) {
            // Gets triggered when there was an error sending the files.
            // Maybe show form again, and notify user of error
            console.log("Erreur de l'envoi.");
        });
      }
});
```

Here is the method use to upload the file (the method is working on another page where I just have the DropzoneJS part, and not a whole form with Dropzone.JS included).

```
    /**
 * Upload the user file to the server
 *
 * @param      \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request  The request
 *
 * @return     string                    ( response message )
 */
public function upload(Request $request)
{
    $userFiles = null;
    $email = $request->input('email');

    // Check if there is already a file associated with the email 
    if ($email) 
    {
        $userFiles = Files::getNonUserFiles($email);
    }
    else 
    {
        return Response::json(array(
            'error'   =>  Lang::get('landing.no_email')
        ), 400);
    }

    // If the non user already has a file online, we block it
    if(!$userFiles->isEmpty())
    {
        return Response::json(array(
            'error'   =>  Lang::get('landing.already_have_file')
        ), 400);
    }

    // Upload settings
    $uploadSettings = uploadSettings::first();

    // If there is a file uploaded
    if ($request->file('file')->isValid())
    {
        // Getting the uploaded file
        $file = $request->file('file');

        // Get the extension of the file
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();

        // Getting allowed extension
        $allowedExt = explode(',' , $uploadSettings->allowedFilesExt);

        // Get the file size
        $size = $file->getSize();

        // File size
        if($size > $uploadSettings->maxFreeFileSize) 
        {
            return Response::json(array(
                'error'   =>  Lang::get('documents.size_too_big')
            ), 400);
        }
        // File type
        else if( !in_array(strtolower($extension), $allowedExt) )
        {
            return Response::json(array(
                'error'   =>  Lang::get('documents.wrong_format')
            ), 400);
        }
        // If everything is all right
        else 
        {
            // Where the file will be uploaded
            $destinationPath = $this->noUserStorageService->storageDirectory();

            // Generate a new date
            $date = time('d-m-Y h:i:s.u');

            if (!preg_match('/^[\x20-\x7E]+$/', $file->getClientOriginalName() ))
            {
                $filename = str_replace(' ','',$date.'_'.generateRandomString(10).'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension());
            }
            else
            {
                $filename = str_replace(' ','',$date.'_'.$file->getClientOriginalName());
                $filename = str_replace("#", "_", $filename);
            }
                $path = $request->file('file')->storeAs(
                    $destinationPath, $filename
                );

                // If file Uploaded Success
                if ($path) 
                {
                    // We create the file into the database
                    $files              = new Files;

                    // File Name
                    $files->name        = pathinfo(strtolower(htmlentities($file->getClientOriginalName())), PATHINFO_FILENAME);
                    $files->server_name = $filename;
                    // File Path
                    $files->path        = preg_replace('/\s+/', '',url('/file/'.pathinfo($filename,PATHINFO_FILENAME)));

                    // File Extention
                    $files->extension   = $extension;
                    $files->user_email  = $email;

                    // File Status
                    $files->status      = 1;
                    $files->auto_sign   = 0;

                    $files->size = $file->getClientSize() ;

                    // Save File Info
                    $files->save();

                    return Response::json(array(
                        'message'   =>  'success'
                    ), 200); 
                }
                else 
                {
                    return Response::json(array(
                        'error'   =>  "Impossible d'envoyer le fichier sur le serveur. Veuillez réessayer."
                    ), 400);
                }
            }
    }   
}
```

I don't think it's coming from my Laravel configuration, because the DropzoneJS classic form (not included in another form) is working fine somewhere else on my project.

What is wrong with my form or dropzone configuration ?

Comment: There are not enough information to help you (no server side code). I found this example here (https://tuts.codingo.me/laravel-5-1-and-dropzone-js-auto-image-uploads-with-removal-links) with dropzone and laravel, maybe this can help you

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link. I'm going to check it right now. I've edited my post with the code used on the sever side. Problem is that it's not coming from the server side because I'm using this method somewhere else on the project and it's working fine, except that I just have the DropzoneJS form which is not included in another form (not like in this special use case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been playing around with this.  One of the customisations the Bootstrap demo makes to vanilla Dropzone is a start button for each individual file.  However, you're not using that start button (your template does not include one).  Also, you have `maxFiles: 1`, and `parallelUploads: 1` (actually you have  `parallelUploads: 20` as well but the 2nd one probably takes precedence).  So it looks like you really only  want 1 file upload on this form, right?  In which case why do you need the this Bootstrap demo approach?  If the goal is to tweak the layout and appearance of the file and upload, you can do that in vanilla Dropzone with [`previewTemplate`](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-previewTemplate), which is a bit simpler, and I think would avoid the problems your seeing.

In any case, the key to the problem is that in the Boostrap demo, the start button is what enqueues the file.  Their config has `autoQueue: false`, so that no files are enqueued automatically.  Instead, they add an event listener every time a file is added:

```
file.previewElement.querySelector(".start").onclick = function() { myDropzone.enqueueFile(file); };
```

You also have `autoQueue: false`, but you have no start button, and no manual enqueuing of files, so your files are never enqueued.  So when you hit submit there is nothing in Dropzone's queue to process, so all you see on the server side are the other form input values (email etc).

The simplest fix is just to remove `autoQueue: false`, so your file will be enqueued as soon as you select it.  In local testing of your code this works for me - the file is included in the data POSTed to the back end.

One thing to note is that when you hit the submit button, there are actually 2 separate POSTs that happen.  First Dropzone posts just the file, and then your form is submitted with your text inputs.  That's going to be another problem bcs it looks like your controller currently expects form data and file upload at once.

It looks like you maybe started working around this already, by `formData.append`ing some of your form inputs to the Dropzone POST.  You could do that for each of your inputs, and then somehow ignore the 2nd POST (or have the `action` point to a different Controller method?).  Alternatively you could have separate controller methods for each POST - use the `form`'s `action` to specify the method to save the form data, and Dropzone's `url` config option to specify a different method to handle the file upload.

**UPDATE**

Here's a clearer example of a way to work around this double POST problem.

In your Javascript, first append each of the inputs in your form to the Dropzone:

```
this.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData) {
    // Get every input on the form
    var data = $('#send-files-form').serializeArray();

    // Append them all to the formData Dropzone will POST
    $.each(data, function(key, el) {
        formData.append(el.name, el.value);
    });
    console.log("Fichier en cours d'envoi.");
});
```

Now you have all your form data, as well as the file, in the POST that Dropzone will do.  That means you can ignore or disable the 2nd POST that happens after Dropzone is done.  To do that, stop the form actually being posted:

```
$("#submit-document").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    myDropzone.processQueue();
});
```

Now there's only 1 POST.  Of course now you have to manually handle what to do after a form submission.  You can do that using the `success` and `error` Dropzone callbacks.  Your controller is already returning JSON with a success or error msg, so maybe you can display it on the front end.  Add some kind of message placeholder in your HTML:

```
<div class="message"></div>
```

And target it in your callbacks:

```
this.on("success", function(files, response) {
    $('div.message').html(response.message);
    myDropzone.removeAllFiles();
    console.log("Succès de l'envoi.");
});

this.on("error", function(files, response) {
    $('div.message').html(response.error);
    console.log("Erreur de l'envoi.");
});
```

Or maybe after a successful submission you want to redirect away to a different page:

```
this.on("success", function(files, response) {
    myDropzone.removeAllFiles();
    window.location('/some/other/place');
    console.log("Succès de l'envoi.");
});
```

Minor thing - the code you include is missing the closing `</form>` tag, which caused me some headaches.  You probably just didn't copy-paste it here from your code, but mentioning it just in case.

One last thing - [the docs seem to be broken on this](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-maxFilesize), but AFAICT `maxFilesize` value should be in MB (search the docs for that string to see some examples).  Your value of `maxFilesize: 3145728` should probably be something like `maxFilesize: 3`.

Comment: THANKS A LOT for your answer, this is saving my life right now, and the project I'm working on. 
Indeed I'm not using the start button because best would be that it uploads the file, only when I click on the submit button of the form. 
For the parallelUploads, this is fixed thanks for noticing.
I want only one file to be upload with the form that's exact.
Sorry for the end of the form, forgot to include it when creating the post.
For maxFileSize, you are right ! 
For the start button I understand the problem now, makes sense. I deleted the autoQueue: false.

Comment: The problem is what you suggested indeed ... It's making two POST request which is complex for me to deal with. 
Problem is that even if I put an URL in the Dropzone configuration if :
- I keep autoProcessQueue: false, nothing is happening except the file to be add in the Queue, and it's the POST request of the form which is triggered, and on my side, I don't have the file posted with the form. So I've only have form data and not the file.

Comment: - If I don't keep it, so having autoProcessQueue: true, the URL from the configuration of the Dropzone is called, and it's making the POST request and uploading the file, even if the user has not clicked on the submit button of the form.

My goal is, if it's possible, to submit and upload the file with the global form to avoid making the upload of the file if the user has not submitted the form. Right now I can only first uploading the file, and then submiting the form. Any idea on what's still wrong with the configuration ?

Comment: How is it working on the example you created on localhost ? Would love to take a look !

Comment: Glad it is helping.  As to my local tests, I really just have your HTML/JS.  I have not tested your controller code, all I am doing is checking what is happening and what is POSTed with browser devtools.  Anyway I updated my answer with a clearer example of one way to work around the 2x POSTs - this is tested and working for me.  I also just found another possibly simpler solution - but it is closer to vanilla Dropzone so you'd have to revert your code back to that: https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/Combine-normal-form-with-Dropzone

Comment: THANKS A LOT. You saved me ! Thanks for your explanations, it's working like a charm !